# Chrome media control - Download button

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, html5-video

How can I modify the Chrome Download button position for audio / video , as it is displayed in an improper position. I try to use 
video::-internal-media-controls-overflow-menu-list
but it doesn't work

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I am having a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52395409/html-5-video-cc-button What have you uncovered so far?

Comment: I found some sort of solve on the post I mentioned above if you are still in need of help.

Comment: @DylanAnlezark thank you anyway though I have moved to another project :3